# How to decrypt password in Laravel 4 when selecting a record from the database using the Eloquent Model Class?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, encryption, laravel

I've a small application where users can make accounts and also edit there accounts inclusive their passwords. I want to insert all the records of the account, which I select from the database, in the inputs of the editform by using the `value="value here"` option.

The case is that I use a Validator to validate the input of the user, this Validator is the same to create and edit an account.:

```
class Account extends Validator {
    public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|alpha|min:2',
        'secondname' => 'alpha_spaces|min:2',
        'lastname' => 'required|alpha|min:2',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:accounts',
        'password' => 'required|alpha_num|between:6,12|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|alpha_num|between:6,12'
    ];
}
```

This is my edit-form:
[image: This is my edit-form]

This is my code where I select the records from the db:

```
$q = Input::get('query');
$result = Account::where('id', '=', $q)->get();
```

In this case will the password be inserted in the input as hashed. So when the user even don't want to change his password it changes, because the hashed password will again be hashed.

So I need in some way select the password unhashed so when the user don't want to edit his password it stays the same.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: What? If the user doesn't change their password (leaves the field blank... don't make password a required field on edit) then remove password property from the model before saving and it will only update fields that are set.... but you can't decrypt a hashed password

Comment: PS Why are you limiting your users to alphanumeric passwords?

Comment: As I said, I use the same Validator for both to create and edit one account. So if I don't make password a required field, it won't require it when a new user is created.

It really isn't that important that the user is limited to alphanumeric passwords, because this project is for school.

Comment: You modify the validation array within the code for the edit, removing the password required from your validation array before calling the validator

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you only want to change a password for a user if he inputs it, and if so, I would've done it like this.

1. I would remove `alpha_num`, `between` and `confirmed` for the `password` rule. Removing that allows for a more secure password.
2. I would add `same:password_confirmation` to the `password` rule, this makes sure both fields are equal.
3. I would remove the rule for `password_confirmation`, `same:password_confirmation` already takes care of that.

So in the end your array should look like this:

```
public static $rules = [
    'name' => 'required|alpha|min:2',
    'secondname' => 'alpha_spaces|min:2',
    'lastname' => 'required|alpha|min:2',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:accounts',
    'password' => ['required', 'same:password_confirmation']
];
```

This works fine when you create a new user, but this will run the password requirement check if we edit a user (your current problem). To fix this we must remove `required` from `password`. Because we now have the `password` rules as an array and we know that `required` is the first item of that array, we can just remove it before running the validation for when updating a user.

We will also need to make sure not to insert an empty `password` and hash it if user typed to change it.

```
$input = Input::all();

// make sure not to insert empty password
if (empty($input['password']))
  unset($input['password']);

// remove the requirement of password
unset(Account::$rules['password'][0]);

// validate our rules
$validator = Validation::make($input, Account::$rules);
if ($validator->fails()) {
  // do something if error
}

// hash if new password
if ( ! empty($input['password']))
    $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);

Account::find($accountId)->update($input);
```